# Graphical programing language for Arduino

Tags: programming, arduino-nano

I am looking for a graphical programming language for a project of mine, where I am using an Arduino.

It HAS to meet the following conditions:

- It supports uploaing sketches to ATmega328 (Arduino Uno/Nano)
- New functions can be defined inside the programming enviroment (I am trying to use a motor connected to an H-bridge with a single command block)
- The program can run on Windows 7
- Libraries can be used inside the code
- C++ can also be used to write the code inside the same program
- Sketches can be uploaded via Bluetooth 4.0

It would be nice if it met the following condition:

- The programming enviroment is easy to use
- The graphical programming language is somewhat similar to Scratch
- The program can be understood by 10-14 year olds with no programming experience

Comment: There is a Scratch extension for Arduino.  I have not used it and I do not know if it satisfies all of your criteria.  http://playground.arduino.cc/Interfacing/Scratch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most full featured Scratch-like environment for Arduino, to my knowledge that is close to your listed criteria is http://www.mblock.cc/

It's currently in beta development for enabling bluetooth uploads and supports a range of "extension" plugins.  I believe you can also add functionality by writing your own extensions if you have sufficient programming knowledge.

The software has more features if you use their mblock hardware, while offering a reduced set of commands for other boards such as the Uno.

[image: Supported Boards]

[image: Arduino code with scratch]

I'm sure you can add library's to your code but at the expense of the scratch-like interface.  A children's visual design tool being able to provide graphical API to libraries written by an open source community is quite a coding challenge.  You can get a feel for this by trying to use any reverse engineering C++ to UML diagram tools.

I recommend perhaps using one of these scratch tools to build simple firmware as a learning tool with the idea of progressing to an actual programming language soon after.

In any case I hope you find what you're looking for among these options for your project.

- http://www.mblock.cc/
- http://s4a.cat/
- http://blog.minibloq.org/p/documentation.html
- http://blog.ardublock.com/engetting-started-ardublockzhardublock/
- https://www.visuino.com/

Answer (score 0):

Give Visuino a look, they are making noise lately: https://www.visuino.com/

Comment: Can you add extensions to it or define functions?